# Print data table to console in tibble format - R

Tags: r, data.table, tibble

Basic data

```
mat=matrix(nrow=100,ncol=30)
dt=data.table(mat)
names(dt)=stri_rand_strings(30,10)
```

When a data.table has a lot of columns its print to console is very cumbersome and very often requires scrolling even if the option "datatable.print.nrows" is set to a low number because there are too many columns or the names of the columns are long. datatable.print.trunc.cols is not helpful as it truncates too many columns off the print. I really like the print format of tibble but don't really use tibbles.

Is there a way to print data.tables with the tibble format without converting a data table to tibble just for printing it? Perhaps by truncating the width of data table columns?

EDIT: I also found this undocumented option datatable.prettyprint.char, which helps a bit reduce the clutter.

Comment: I use the `options(datatable.print.topn = 5, datatable.print.class = TRUE, datatable.print.trunc.cols = TRUE)`, and the output is in many ways the same as a tibble's output. If `trunc.cols` is not working, perhaps your screen-width (`options(width=..)`) is too small?

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the suggestion. I don't think it's a problem with my screen width, the behavior of trunc.cols is really different from what tibble does. Tibble truncates part of each column instead to an x amount of columns. Digging a bit more I found datatable.prettyprint.char which is an undocumented option, it helps a bit but still not to the level of tibble.

Comment: I had forgotten that one, yes I use that too. I don't find tibble's presentation to be significantly better, just different. Often I prefer the consistency of `data.table`'s widths over `tibble`'s waffling (*Beauty is in the eye of the beholder*).